# How to fix android studio gradle plugin issue?

Tags: plugins, android-gradle-plugin

I am a beginner of Android Studio.
When I import project, the IDE shows the following error.

"Plugin with id 'com.android.model.application' not found" from build.gradle.

Thanks in advance for any advice for the issue.

Below is the build.gradle link:
https://github.com/joaopedronardari/OpenCV-AndroidSamples/blob/master/app/build.gradle

Comment: Post your build.gradle file

Comment: Thanks. I received the source from : https://github.com/joaopedronardari/OpenCV-AndroidSamples/blob/master/app/build.gradle